# Working with Likert scales in SPSS

Tags: spss, likert

I performed a survey using a Likert 1 to 5 scale (totally agree/agree/neutral/ disagree/totally disagree) on 12 questions which are split into 3 statements which the respondent places a value of between 1 to 5 dependent on how much they agree or disagree - there are 36 statements in total.

Respondents:

```
Group 1                          Group 2
architects UK   140 replied      Architects US   100 replied
engineers UK    140 replied      Engineers US    100 replied
Contractors Uk  140 replied      Contractors US  100 replied
```

The data is in Excel.

#### Questions:

1. How do I input them in SPSS?
2. How do I work out the frequency of replies for each recipient?
3. How do I work out frequency of replies i.e agrees/disagrees etc for each group?
4. How can I rank each individual question (12 of them)? Remember, there are 3 individual statements to each question.
5. How do I compare UK architects to US architects to show congruence or not?
6. How would show correlation between the two groups UK and US?
7. Will SPSS develop graphs etc for me showing frequency or correlation?

Comment: You should check out the resources on the SPSS tag wiki, http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/spss/info . The article, Programming and Data Management for IBM Statistics would be a good start to answer your questions.

Comment: Usually independent questions are asked separately, so you have a better chance to get answers of you ask them one by one. You will find that for some there have been  very similar questions already answered.

Comment: In SPSS you can go to Help...Tutorial or Help...Index (and once you've chosen a topic, click Show Me to get the tutorial for that topic).  A couple of hours spent on this should answer most of your questions in a visual and/or verbal way.

Answer (score 8):

#### 1. How do I input them in SPSS?

You can open an Excel file in SPSS.
Use the standard file open option, and select `file type = *xls`.
Try to ensure that the first row has the variable names.

#### 2. How do I work out the frequency of replies for each recipient?

- Do you mean the frequency of responses for each question?
- Check out the menu `Descriptive Statistics - Frequencies`

#### 3. How do I work out frequency of replies i.e agrees/disagrees etc for each group?

- Check out `Descriptive Statistics - Crosstabs`

#### 4. How can I rank each individual question (12 of them)? Remember, there are 3 individual statements to each question.

- Rank them in terms of what?
- If you intend to rank each question in terms of their mean (e.g., on a one to five scale). One way would be to run `Descriptive Statistics - Descriptives` and get the mean for each item. Then copy and paste the table of item means into Excel and sort by the `Mean` column.

#### 5. How do I compare UK architects to US architects to show congruence or not?

- Check out `Descriptive Statistics - Explore`; you could also look at some of the compare mean options.

#### 6. How would show correlation between the two groups UK and US?

- These are different participants so I don't know what you mean by asking for correlations.

#### 7. Will SPSS develop graphs etc for me showing frequency or correlation?

- Yes, it will.
- Just have a play around with the Graphs menu (e.g., `Legacy - Scatter` or `Legacy - Bar`)

#### General Suggestions

It sounds like you need a basic book explaining how to use SPSS.
A good one is the SPSS Survival Manual.
I also wrote a [120 page PDF Introduction to SPSS](http://web.psych.unimelb.edu.au/jkanglim/Anglim2006-SPSSIntroductionWorkshop.pdf) several years back which explains all the things mentioned above with examples.

Comment: I stumbled on this "120 page PDF Introduction to SPSS" 12 years after the original post. Bummer that the link doesn't work anymore.