# Reporting the general perception of tested sample

Tags: spss, t-test

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Working with Likert scales in SPSS](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/9807/working-with-likert-scales-in-spss)

I have a data sample of which recorded individual's perception on whether a specific option is viable or not. The data was recorded on a lickert scale of 1 - 5. So basically, I'm looking to say that the "general perception of the sample is ____"
The mean = 2.83 and std. dev. 1.2007.

Firstly, what is the analysis that I should run for this? 
I ran a one-sample t-test in SPSS against 3 as >3 means the perception is favourable. The reported significance was > 0.5 (I divided the reported significance by 2 as SPSS runs a 2-tailed test rather than one tailed which is I believe is what I want).

I'm unsure now whether I ran the right test or how to interpret this finding, if I have done the correct analysis.

Comment: This question is thoroughly answered in many of the threads with the [Likert] tag, such as http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/9807/working-with-likert-scales-in-spss .

Comment: Sorry, but I don't think I see the answer to this in the question that's linked. I believe the question is more related to one-tailed t test rather than likert scale. What I'm looking for is the percentage of the sample that falls behind a specific value in the distribution. I don't think descriptives, crosstabs etc gives me that information. Sorry if I've understood correctly.

Comment: Then please restate the question to clarify what you really are looking for.  After editing it you should be able to reopen it.  However, first search this site for similar questions (about one-tailed t-tests): there are lots of them and it's likely your question has already been answered.

Comment: Actually, I found what I looking for by using the Cumulative Frequencies column of the frequency tables. That'll do for the problem at hand.